# Pressing backspace in UITextfield not deleting

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Currently I have a textfield in the format ###/##.  When typing it types in the correct format but for some strange reason when deleting it will only delete until the '/' sign and won't delete before that. For example if the text is (555/66), it will delete until the (555/) then it stops deleting. Any idea how to fix this? Here is the code.

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

 if string.count == 0 {
                var text = textField.text!
                let start = text.startIndex
                let beginRange = text.index(start, offsetBy: range.location)
                let endRange = text.index(start, offsetBy: range.location + range.length)
                text = String(text.prefix(upTo: beginRange))
                    + String(text.suffix(from: endRange))
                text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "")
                if text.count >= 2 {
                    text = String(text.prefix(3)) + "/" + String(text.dropFirst(3))
                }

                textField.text = text

                return false
            }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't stop deleting. Your code simply adds back the `/` that you just removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this , if you have  ###/## format for textfield

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

            if string.count != 0 {
                    var text = textField.text!

                    if range.location == 3
                    {
                             text.append("/")
                             textField.text = text
                    }
                    if range.location == 6
                    {
                            return false
                    }
              }
            return true
    }
```